# Android: how to set button disable right after the method setEnabled(false)?

Tags: android, button, attributes, widget, setter

This question is not only limit for Button or this setter.
For example, here a button listener:

```
runButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                runButton.setEnabled(false);
                runScript();//This function will take a long time!! 
            }
        });
```

When this button is clicked, I want it be disabled immediately. However, practically, I see this button won't get disabled until all the methods finished, that is after the method runScript() finishes, the button actually turns grey.
So, could anyone tell me how to make the button disabled right after that line?

Answer (score 2):

What happens is the `runScript` method blocks the UI thread. What you want to do inside your `onClick` method is disable the button then run the script in a different thread, like so

```
runButton.setEnabled(false);
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
            runScript();//This function will take a long time!! 
    }
}).start();
```

More information found here:

- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html

Comment: Thanks. What I want to do inside OnClick is to runScript that is to generate traffic with a server, a lot of traffic, which is used to test our channel performance. I shall try your suggestion. Thank a lot! I don't know much about multi threading.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule of thumb, you want to avoid doing anything that may take a long time on the UI thread. What you can do in your click listener is spawn a new thread that does the long-running method in the background. The android [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) class provides a lot of support methods for having background threads that can send updates back to the UI via progress events.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling runButton.invalidate() immediately after setEnabled(false) method

Also

You should not have long running methods in the UI thread transfer runScript() to an asynch task. Button state will get updated faster

```
runButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        runButton.setEnabled(false);
        MyTask asyncTask = new MyTask();
        asyncTask.execute();
    }
});
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<void, void, String> {
 protected String doInBackground(void) {
     runScripts();
     //set to something relevant to your app
     String result ="";
     return result;
 }

 protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
     //do something
 }
```

}

I

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's so helpful.